# Alembic: How to print SQL for the last non-commited yet resivion in one command?

Tags: sqlalchemy, alembic

When I create migrations via Alembic, I want to check the result in SQL format. And the last only migration is interesting.

`alembic upgrade --sql head` -- this command print SQL for all revisions

It's possible to print SQL for the specific migrations using their identifiers:
`alembic upgrade --sql 5fb648aeb2e7:head`

But it's not very convenient to do it, because it's necessary to type another command  `alembic history` and to find the second last revision.

They say there are relative migration identifiers:
https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#relative-migration-identifiers

I've tried `alembic --upgrade sql +1`, `alembic --upgrade sql +0`, but it doesn't work.

Is it possible to print in SQL the last revision in one command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interestingly, `alembic upgrade rev:rev+1 --sql` works but `alembic upgrade rev-1:rev --sql` does not.

However, since the first line of `alembic history` includes the head revision and its previous revision, it's possible to do with a shell pipeline (POSIX):

`alembic upgrade --sql $(alembic history | head -1 | sed 's/ -> /:/' | cut -f1 -d' ')`